# How to achieve a reference-counted shared instance in Autofac?

Tags: autofac, reference-counting

I have a service `IService` that several components depend on.  The components come and go depending on user actions.

It so happens that the implementation of `IService` is expensive, and I want 1 instance shared across all components.  So far so good, I can use:

```
builder.RegisterType<ExpensiveStuff>().As<IService>().SingleInstance();
```

However, I don't want to `ExpensiveStuff` to live forever once built; I only want it to exist when one or more components holds a reference to it.

Is there a built in means of achieving this in Autofac?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to make sure that your usage of those dependencies happen within an [instance scope](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope).

The Orchard project could be a source of inspiration here. They use a set of scopes for Unit of Work; [see the `ShellContainerFactory.cs` source file](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/95f0539354b2#src%2fOrchard%2fEnvironment%2fShellBuilders%2fShellContainerFactory.cs).

Comment: I understand I can use an instance per scope to share an instance across multiple components; but what I'm not seeing in the source you reference is how to get the components themselves to control the lifetime of the instance, unless I build them all within a scope

Comment: I believe that is the answer.  "Build them all within a scope".  Otherwise, there is no way for Autofac to predict when you no longer need the reference.  Sounds like you could use a Unit of Work pattern for the batch of work that uses those references, and just make a scope for that.